# Unmarshalling top-level JSON array in Go

Tags: arrays, json, go

I'm learning Go by writing a simple http server and I need to handle some JSON responses.

With an object response, I can unmarshal it idiomatically with 2 lines of code:
    structResult := Foo{}
    json.Unmarshal(structBody, &structResult)

I don't know how to do the same for an array response (see the example below). Is there a way to specify (possibly via json tag) that top-level array should go into a given struct field?

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "encoding/json"

type Foo struct {
    Id uint64 `json:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

type BaseResult struct {
    Error string  `json:"error"`
}

type FooResult struct {
    BaseResult
    Foos []Foo
}

func main() {
    // Simple and works.
    structBody := []byte(`{"id": 1,"name": "foo"}`)
    structResult := Foo{}
    json.Unmarshal(structBody, &structResult)
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", structResult)

    // Doesn't work.
    arrayBody := []byte(`[{"id": 1,"name": "foo"},{"id": 2,"name": "bar"},{"id": 3,"name": "foobar"}]`) 
    arrayResult := FooResult{}
    json.Unmarshal(arrayBody, &arrayResult)
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", arrayResult)
}
```

I know I could make FooResult an array:

```
type FooResult []Foo
```

but then I lose the ability to specify base object which I would like to use to store error message and such. I also know that I can unmarshal into &fooResult.Foos directly, but I want the code to work with both objects and arrays.

UPDATE

Implementing UnmarshalJSON as suggested by @dyoo partially solves my problem, but I was hoping that I could use BaseResult to store parse error in case JSON has a different structure:

```
arrayBody := []byte(`{"error": "foo"}`)
arrayResult := FooResult{}
json.Unmarshal(arrayBody, &arrayResult)
fmt.Printf("%#v\n", arrayResult)
```

Of course I could implement more complex logic inside UnmarshalJSON - but isn't there a simpler way to do it?

Comment: Recommendation: rename `FooResult` to `ArrayResult`.  Using `Foo` as any part of a name is often dubious because it doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Sure, I only used the name "foo" in this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement the [`json.Unmarshaler`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler) interface in your `FooResult`, to customize exactly how it responds to unmarshaling.  (Similarly, there's a [`json.Marshaler`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler) interface.)

Add:

```
func (f *FooResult) UnmarshalJSON(bs []byte) error {
    return json.Unmarshal(bs, &f.Foos)
}
```

after which your code should otherwise work.  http://play.golang.org/p/oMdoB2e-rB

You might try something like:

```
func (f *FooResult) UnmarshalJSON(bs []byte) error {
    err1 := json.Unmarshal(bs, &f.BaseResult)
    err2 := json.Unmarshal(bs, &f.Foos)
    if err1 != nil && err2 != nil {
        // Arbitrarily choose an error.
        return err1
    }
    return nil
}
```

although even this is beginning to look dubious.  Handling *union type* results is not quite what the json library is designed to handle automatically for you.  You'll need to explicitly code the coercion logic if your JSON has dynamic type.

See: [How to unmarshall an array of different types correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364181/how-to-unmarshall-an-array-of-different-types-correctly) and http://blog.golang.org/json-and-go for related issues.

Comment: Thank you. This answers my problem, but the real reason for my question was that I was hoping to use base struct to store error in case when returned JSON has different structure (many APIs are enveloped this way). I wonder if that's possible.

Comment: You don't need to implement UnmarshalJSON, just specify Foos when you unmarshal. I have an example in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Just specify `Foos` when you Unmarshal

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "encoding/json"

type Foo struct {
    Id   uint64 `json:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

type BaseResult struct {
    Error string `json:"error"`
}

type FooResult struct {
    BaseResult
    Foos []Foo
}

func main() {
    // Simple and works.
    structBody := []byte(`{"id": 1,"name": "foo"}`)
    structResult := Foo{}
    json.Unmarshal(structBody, &structResult)
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", structResult)

    // Doesn't work.
    arrayBody := []byte(`[{"id": 1,"name": "foo"},{"id": 2,"name": "bar"},{"id": 3,"name": "foobar"}]`)
    arrayResult := FooResult{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(arrayBody, &arrayResult.Foos); err != nil {
        arrayResult.BaseResult.Error = string(arrayBody)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", arrayResult)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I know I can do that, but my whole point is to keep parsing logic close to struct and avoid writing code for each different case. @dyoo's solution via UnmarshalJSON is nicer.